# How can i call my user input method better into my main method, to check for win conditions?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, input, netbeans, java.util.scanner

I am having a hard time trying to use my calledNumsInput method in my main method to check for victory conditions, where the user input matches a value in the randomly generated 2d array.

For now I have a placeholder to show where I want to start implementing conditions, and that is the If statement with the board[][] value at the end of my main method. Will I just have to make a ton of If statements centered around a calledNumsInput(). Or is there a way to implement that method into win conditions.

I am very new to coding, so I do not mind lamens logic. I encourage it.

Thank you for your time.
    package bingoWood;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class bingoWood {
static ArrayList<Integer> random=newArrayList<Integer>();
 private static Random r = new Random();
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("B  I  N  G  O");
    int[][] board = new int[5][5];        
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
       for(int j =0; j <board.length; j++){
           if(j==0)
               board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(15, 1);
           else if(j==1)
               board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(30, 16);
           else if(j==2)
               board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(45, 31);
           else if(j==3)
               board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(60, 46);
           else if(j==4)
               board[i][j] =     getUniqueRandom (75, 61);               
         if(i==board.length/2 && j==board.length/2) board[i][j] = 0;
           System.out.printf("%-3s", board[i][j]);
       }
       System.out.println("");     
    }  
    if(board[0][0] == calledNumsInput() && board[1][1] == calledNumsInput()     //Diagonal TopLeft - BotRight Win condition
       && board[2][2] == calledNumsInput() && board[3][3] == calledNumsInput()
       && board[4][4] == calledNumsInput())                               
        System.out.println("BINGO");                                                    

    if(board[0][4] == calledNumsInput() && board[1][3] == calledNumsInput()     //Diagonal TopRight - BotLeft Win condition
       && board[2][2] == calledNumsInput() && board[3][1] == calledNumsInput()
       && board[4][0] == calledNumsInput()) 
        System.out.println("BINGO");

    if(board[4][4] == calledNumsInput() && board[3][3] == calledNumsInput()     
       && board[2][2] == calledNumsInput() && board[1][1] == calledNumsInput()
       && board[0][0] == calledNumsInput()) 
        System.out.println("BINGO");


}
static int getUniqueRandom(int max, int min){
    int num = r.nextInt(max-min+1) + min;
    while (random.contains(num)) {
        num = r.nextInt(max-min+1) + min;
    }
    random.add(num);
    return num;
  }
   static int calledNumsInput(){        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Called Number: ");
    int calledNum = input.nextInt();    

    return calledNum;
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to play BINGO so i'm not getting your point. Please explain it to a bingo novice. And this time i'll only help you conceptually.

Comment: Okay so in bingo, if you get 5 numbers in a row going any direction, you get BINGO. the center of the board is a free space. So I am trying to list the possible victory conditions without just spamming the code with a ton of if() statements.

Comment: Ill update the code in the question. It better displays my concerns.

Comment: Structed the way it is now with the if() statements, I have to input the numbers to test them in order of the if() statements as each one in order. Rather than If I was to input a win condition randomly. If I try that now, the code ends.

Comment: calling calledNumsInput() again will result asking user to enter the value again and again you have to store it somewhere

Comment: do you want to tally user input with the 2D array and find if it matches vertically or horizontally or diagonally

Comment: How I go about having the user input the "called" numbers isn't too important. The over all program is more of a test, to see if the input values match the array and can give a result of BINGO (or 5 in a row anywhere) So I suppose I could make the last method store up to a certain amount of input values, then just call it and test them using the conditions all at once. But one at a time is easier I think for this purpose.

Comment: I want to try and change all the possible If() statements into a format in which the user can input 5 values that equal bingo (5 in a row) in any given order. Im not sure how to link all the possible win conditions together so that can be done.

Comment: also I just realized that 0 has to be input by the user every time as well, instead of being a free given value. or free space.

Comment: you can create a bool array and store true if a inputted number is found on the bingo list later compare that bool array  to find verticals, horizontals or diagonals to figure out if it is BINGO or NOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the problem here is the solution to that. I will insist you to try to understand the code until you get it fully. Programming is an art the more you do it yourself the more you will grow.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Solution {
static ArrayList<Integer> random=new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static Random r = new Random();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("B  I  N  G  O");
    int[][] board = new int[5][5];        
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
       for(int j =0; j <board.length; j++){
           if(j==0)
               board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(15, 1);
           else if(j==1)
               board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(30, 16);
           else if(j==2)
               board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(45, 31);
           else if(j==3)
               board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom(60, 46);
           else if(j==4)
               board[i][j] = getUniqueRandom (75, 61);               
         if(i==board.length/2 && j==board.length/2) board[i][j] = 0;
           System.out.printf("%-3s", board[i][j]);
       }
       System.out.println("");     
    }  
    boolean[][] myBingo = new boolean[5][5];
    while(true) {
        int calledNumsInput = calledNumsInput();
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
            for(int j =0; j <board.length; j++){
                if(calledNumsInput == board[i][j]) {
                    System.out.println("B " + board[i][j] + " is on the Board!");   
                    myBingo[i][j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isBingo(myBingo)) {
            System.out.println("BINGO");break;
        }
    }
}
static boolean isBingo(boolean[][] myBingo) {
    int hcount = 0, vcount = 0, dcount = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < myBingo.length; i++){
        for(int j =0; j <myBingo.length; j++){
            if(myBingo[i][j] == true)
                hcount++; 
        }
        if(hcount == 5) return true;
        else hcount = 0; 
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < myBingo.length; i++){
        for(int j =0; j <myBingo.length; j++){
            if(myBingo[j][i] == true)
                vcount++; 
        }
        if(vcount == 5) return true;
        else vcount = 0; 
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < myBingo.length; i++){
        for(int j =0; j <myBingo.length; j++){
            if((i == j) && (myBingo[i][j] == true))
                dcount++; 
        }
        if((i == myBingo.length-1) && dcount == 5) return true;
        else if((i == myBingo.length-1)) dcount = 0; 
    }
    for(int i =0; i < myBingo.length; i++){
        for(int j =0; j < myBingo.length; j++){
            if((i+j == myBingo.length-1) && (myBingo[i][j] == true)) 
                dcount++;               
            }
        if((i == myBingo.length-1) && dcount == 5) return true;
        else if((i == myBingo.length-1)) dcount = 0; 
    }
    return false;
}
static int getUniqueRandom(int max, int min){
    int num = r.nextInt(max-min+1) + min;
    while (random.contains(num)) {
        num = r.nextInt(max-min+1) + min;
    }
    random.add(num);
    return num;
 }
 static int calledNumsInput(){        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Called Number: ");
    int calledNum = input.nextInt();    

    return calledNum;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for taking the spot of those If Statements if I can get it to end after getting 5 inputs in a row that are correct.

```
for(int i = 0; i <5; i++){
        for(int j =0; j < 5; j++){
    if(board[i][j] == calledNumsInput())                               
        System.out.println("Is on the board");                                                    
        } 
        System.out.println("BINGO");
    }
```